# if-else loop condition is not working using java swing?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I'm trying to fetch database records of user name and password and validate using if-else statement. Final else statement is not displaying message dialog. I'm stuck with this, suggest me a solution and say where i done mistake.

My complete code

```
String s1 = id.getText();
   String s2 = new String(pass.getPassword());

   try
   {
       Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/twitter_db","arunachalam","");

       String sql = "select userid, password from user_reg where userid='"+s1+"'";
       PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
       ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
       while(rs.next())
       {
           if((rs.getString("userid").equals(s1)) && (rs.getString("password").equals(s2)))
           {
               dispose();
               showMessageDialog(null,"Login Successfully");
               new UserPage().setVisible(true);
           }
           else if((rs.getString("userid").equals(s1)) && (!rs.getString("password").equals(s2)))
           {
               showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Password");

           }
           else
           {
               showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid User");

           }
       }
   }   
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }
```

Comment: *Final else statement is not displaying message dialog* - could one of the `if` or `if else` be entered, therefore not entering the final `else`

Comment: can you post the complete code?it will be easy to track..

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is `ng-if-else`?

Comment: s i will hold on a sec.

Comment: what is the point of the `else if`? Also note that you should **never** create sql queries with + like you did

Comment: Without using + how to initialize parameters, is there any way to resolve this.

Comment: are you sure you are getting the data from database? because according to code you are not doing anything in case no data was found in Database..

Comment: Why do you use `new String` for `s2`?

Comment: 1) Your code will do nothing in case the resultset is empty, i.e. when the user ID is not found in the database because `rs.next()` will return false. 2) Meet my friend [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: In which case do you expect that the message box from the last else should be displayed? Your result set contains only entries where the userid is what you are search for, and the password either matches (first if) or it doesn't match (second if) - the third case (userid does not match) is never going to happen

Comment: It a mistake, i didn't seen exactly what am doing. Thanks to all for giving me a suggestion about condition statements working.

Answer (score 0):

You checked same condition twice for user id and password so every time it checks first else if statement and it does't satisfy final else if.
Obeserve in your below piece of source code.

```js
 else if((rs.getString("userid").equals(s1)) && (!rs.getString("password").equals(s2)))
           {
               showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Password");

           }
           else if((rs.getString("userid").equals(s1)) && (!rs.getString("password").equals(s2)))
           {
               showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Password");

           }
```

May be you are trying for below code that i have updated

```js
// check for user id not equal
else if((!rs.getString("userid").equals(s1)) && (rs.getString("password").equals(s2)))
           {
               showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect User Id");

           }
           else if((rs.getString("userid").equals(s1)) && (!rs.getString("password").equals(s2)))
           {
               showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Password");

           }
```